# Need Clarification on Trig Substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

$$\int\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^\frac{3}{2}}\ \mathrm dx$$
becomes

$$\sin\theta = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

I am aware that we would use $x = a^2\tan^2\theta$. and that our answer before we plug in from the triangle becomes $\sin\theta$.

I just took a test and got the answer of

$$\sin\theta = \frac{x}{(x^2+1)^\frac{3}{2}}$$

Why does the $\dfrac{3}{2}$ become  $\dfrac{1}{2}$ when we are plugging in for $\sin\theta$?

Comment: What does "$\int \frac{x}{(x^2 + 1)^{3/2}}$ becomes $\sin\theta = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$" mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd write $\displaystyle \int \frac 1 {(x^2+1)^{3/2}} \Big( x\, dx\Big) = \int \frac 1 {u^{3/2}} \left( \frac 1 2\,du\right) = \cdots,$ etc.

But if you must use a trigonometric substitution you can do this:
\begin{align}
x & = \tan\theta \\
dx & = \sec^2\theta\,d\theta \\[10pt]
\int \frac x {(1+x^2)^{3/2}} \,dx & = \int \frac{\tan\theta}{\sec^3\theta} \, \sec^2\theta\,d\theta = \int \sin\theta\,d\theta = -\cos\theta + C \\[10pt]
& = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} + C
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't need  any trigonometric substitution $$\int  \frac { x }{ \left( 1+x^{ 2 } \right) ^{ \frac { 3 }{ 2 }  } } dx=\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \int  \frac { d\left( 1+{ x }^{ 2 } \right)  }{ \left( 1+x^{ 2 } \right) ^{ \frac { 3 }{ 2 }  } } =\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \int { { \left( 1+{ x }^{ 2 } \right)  }^{ -\frac { 3 }{ 2 }  } } d\left( 1+{ x }^{ 2 } \right) =\\ =\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \frac { { \left( 1+{ x }^{ 2 } \right)  }^{ -\frac { 3 }{ 2 } +1 } }{ -\frac { 3 }{ 2 } +1 } =-\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 1+{ x }^{ 2 } }  } +C$$

Comment: I did it on an integral calculator after my exam and it says to use trig-sub, also, the answer wouldn't be negative, so im not entirely sure where you got the negative. The answer is also $\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} + C$

Comment: No,my answer is correct,are you sure that the answer is differen? may be you have written different integral.And I just wrote more detail

Comment: my apologies, you are correct. I accidentally put a 1 on the top instead of x in the integral calculator